# Jquery trigger an event to change the text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello This Question ma seem a bit lame but its really a out of understanding

1. in this site [Azure Price Calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/?)
2. click virtual machine
3. Scroll down[image]
4. **when i manually change the per month price changes**

but when i change via console jquery it is not changing

```
$("input[name=count]").val(2);
     $("input[name=count]").keydown();
     $("input[name=count]").keypress();
     $("input[name=count]").keyup();
     $("input[name=count]").blur();
```

Comment: Events aren't fired when you change the value via code.  Try `$("input").trigger("change")`.

Comment: @freedomn-m no i did it

Comment: please share relevant html code and are there multiple input with same name as count?

Comment: *"no I did it"* - sorry, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar html is on that link and no there are no html with the same name

Comment: *"on that link"* - as per votes: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.".

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried ` $("input").trigger("change")` the text value dint change in the per month price section